# Scraping ebay image thumbnail with Cheerio and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, axios, cheerio

I am able to get title, price, date, etc., with Nodejs, Axios and Cheerio from an ebay search, but I am having trouble getting the img thumbnail url into my items.json file.

Here is my code to get the ebay search and selecting the data:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

async function scrapeEBayItems(url) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

    const items = [];

    $('li.s-item').each((index, element) => {
      const title = $(element).find('div.s-item__title').text().trim();
      const image = $(element).find('a.s-item__image-wrapper.image-treatment').attr('img');
      const price = $(element).find('span.s-item__price').text().trim();
      const date = $(element).find('span.s-item__listingDate').text().trim();
      const shipping = $(element).find('span.s-item__shipping.s-item__logisticsCost').text().trim();
      const itemUrl = $(element).find('a.s-item__link').attr('href');

      items.push({
        title,
        image,
        price,
        date,
        shipping,
        itemUrl
      });
    });

    const data = JSON.stringify(items, null, 2);
    fs.writeFileSync('items.json', data);

    console.log(`Scraped ${items.length} items from ${url}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

scrapeEBayItems('https://www.ebay.com/sch/267/i.html?_nkw=stack+overflow&_saact=1&LH_AvailTo=1&_sop=10&LH_BIN=1');
```

The producted items.json item looks like this:

```
  {
    "title": "OVERFLOW: LIVING ABOVE LIFE'S LIMITS By Hagin Kenneth Jr **Mint Condition**",
    "price": "THB618.28",
    "date": "Apr-4 16:43",
    "shipping": "+THB964.11 shipping",
    "itemUrl": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/185843000152?epid=118963779&hash=item2b451b2358%3Ag%3AgcwAAOSw-TlkLLYg&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAAwBNfcRQy1hqZOILlpIg9qzmF2xeYVuewSycduJC7Tobp51lv5NrYtVauVVrI83ASg%2BfGc2lppd3JMWvoRP21tXgKoCLdwYCkiewNfo%2F6LVl%2F0X6HH2jZVl09c6UkY5dRcZZxw0akbrWpXPFOOZ33RlFYZdn%2FDCiIZFP6MqSzLN7an4LoD%2BkgAoFaL0B4vfcQCaXZuOMuDA64ki56Zho%2FuB%2Fb4T%2BZi6Vau%2FOqDdze04%2FHfArHuVdyrzDhyIXu0PN19w%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR-Lw0Nf1YQ&LH_BIN=1"
  },
```

Here is the snippet I am trying to extract the image url from:

```
<div class="s-item__image-wrapper image-treatment"><img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/gcwAAOSw-TlkLLYg/s-l300.webp" loading="eager" fetchpriority="high" onload="SITE_SPEED.ATF_TIMER.measure(this); if (performance &amp;&amp; performance.mark) { performance.mark(&quot;first-meaningful-paint&quot;); };if(this.width === 80 &amp;&amp; this.height === 80) {window.SRP.metrics.incrementCounter('imageEmptyError');}" onerror="window.SRP.metrics.incrementCounter('imageLoadError');" alt="OVERFLOW: LIVING ABOVE LIFE'S LIMITS By Hagin Kenneth Jr **Mint Condition**" data-atftimer="1682242917643"></div>
```

I would like to have the line:
    `"image": "https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/gcwAAOSw-TlkLLYg/s-l300.webp",`
as part of the item.json file.

I have tried about thirty different variations of
      `const image = $(element).find('a.s-item__image-wrapper.image-treatment').attr('img');`

but cannot seem to grab the img address.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to select an `img` property of some `a` tag with class `...`, but need to select `src` property of an `img` within a `div` with class `...` so you should change :

```js
const image = $(element).find('a.s-item__image-wrapper.image-treatment').attr('img');
```

to

```js
const image = $(element).find('div.s-item__image-wrapper.image-treatment > img').attr('src');
```